# Bitwise operator in case statement

Tags: bitwise-operators

I do not understand the following c++ statement:

```
int c;
switch (c) {
  case 'a': ... ;
  case 'c' | 0x100: ... ;
  case 'c': ...;
}
```

What is the difference between *case 'c'* and *case 'c' | 0x100*? Isn't it the same and *case 'c'* is never reached?

Comment: Tag the language. No, it's not the same if `c` does not already have the bits making up `0x100` set in it.

Comment: `'c' | 0x100 = 0b0 0110 0011 | 0b1 0000 0000 = 0b1 0110 0011 = 355`. Thus, this case will only be entered if `c = 355`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those are two different numbers.

'c' equals to 0x063

'c'|0x100 equals to 0x163